# i want to make a counter function dynamic in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have called a counter function in loop. there are 4 items per page.
i have passed $i in loop and written 4 functions
but if i changed pagination limit to 5 or 10 ,it is not a good solution
anybody can help me to solve it?
here is my div in foreach loop where l called function

```
<div class="tick"
         data-value="'.$start.'"
         data-did-init="handleTickInit'.$i.'">

        <div data-layout="horizontal center" 
             data-repeat="true"
           ">

            <div data-view="swap"
                ></div>

        </div>
```

handleTickInit'.$i is function

```
 function handleTickInit2(tick) {

        var value = tick.value;
        var target = 0;

        var timer = Tick.helper.interval(function() {

            // have we reached the donation target yet?
            if (value>=target) {
                // no, keep going

                var realprice=$("#realprice-2").val();

               var startdate=$("#startdate-2").val();


             var currenttime =  Math.round((new Date()).getTime()/1000);

              var stepsec=$("#stepsec-2").val();
              // alert(stepsec);

              var diffsec=currenttime-startdate;
             var loss=diffsec*stepsec;

                   var start=realprice-loss;

                tick.value =  start.toFixed(4);
             $("#saveval-2").val(start);
            // value= tick.value ;
            }
            else {
                // yes, stop the timer
                timer.stop();
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

please give some solution to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var handleTickInit = {};
var num = 5;


var handleFunc = function() {
  return function (tick) {

        var value = tick.value;
        var target = 0;

        var timer = Tick.helper.interval(function() {

            // have we reached the donation target yet?
            if (value>=target) {
                // no, keep going

                var realprice=$("#realprice-2").val();

               var startdate=$("#startdate-2").val();


             var currenttime =  Math.round((new Date()).getTime()/1000);

              var stepsec=$("#stepsec-2").val();
              // alert(stepsec);

              var diffsec=currenttime-startdate;
             var loss=diffsec*stepsec;

                   var start=realprice-loss;

                tick.value =  start.toFixed(4);
             $("#saveval-2").val(start);
            // value= tick.value ;
            }
            else {
                // yes, stop the timer
                timer.stop();
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
}


for(var i = 0; i< num; i++){
   handleTickInit[i] = handleFunc();
}

console.log(handleTickInit);
```

All your handle tick functions are in `handleTickInit`;

Comment: where that num is used

Comment: how will affect num in this function

Comment: Please share your code in any online editor ( jsfiddle , plukr etc ) so that i can provide any help.

Comment: hai, there? hellooo

Comment: are you here @frontend

Comment: can you come in chat here

Comment: @ANGELA Yes how can i help here.

Comment: can we go to chat room here

Comment: i do not have privileged to create chat room. If you have then ping me there.

Comment: am also dont have much reputation , :(